# reevaluate wildcard in make

Tags: android-ndk, gnu-make

In my Makefile, I want to check if a certain file exists, do something, and check again. Using gnu make, I cannot. Here is the simple example:

```
$(info $(wildcard OK))
$(shell touch OK)
$(info $(wildcard OK))
```

If I run `make` once, I see two empty lines. If I run `make` again, both lines are `OK`.

I thought, maybe `$(eval)` will let me get the updated answer. Alas,

```
$(eval $$(info $$(wildcard OK)))
```

produces the same answer, as if `make` has some way to predict all wildcard calculations before it starts evaluating other commands.

I need this to satisfy the checks performed by Android NDK: I must generate a [*prebuilt shared library*](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/core/prebuilt-shared-library.mk) on the fly.

Comment: This works fine in 4.2.1 :-)

Comment: Had a look in the git log but could find no smoking gun. Does fail in 3.81. Works in 3.82, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 4.2.1. Yeah I know, gotta get out more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work because, for performance, make maintains an internal cache of the directory contents.  Currently that cache is only updated when make runs a rule: then the target the rule is defined to create will be added to the cache.  In your situation make has no way to know that the filesystem has been modified so it won't update the cache.

You have to use the shell, rather than `wildcard`; the shell doesn't know about make's internal caches:

```
$(info $(wildcard OK))
$(shell touch OK)
$(info $(shell [ -f OK ] && echo OK))
```

Clearly this is a bogus example but I'm sure your real code is significantly different than this.

The only other alternative is to turn the command you need to run into a rule.  But again, since the question bears little relation to what you're really trying to do I can't suggest a solution that would work for that.

Comment: My goal is to utilize the [prebuilt_shared_library.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/build/core/prebuilt-shared-library.mk) script in Android NDK for a library that I must build myself. The NDK framework uses $(wildcard) function to verify that the library file is present, but I want to build it myself.

Comment: It looks like, the cache is per directory; and it is created the first time the `$(wildcard)` function is evaluated for this directory. This is probably enough for me to produce a workaround.

Comment: I will do exactly the opposite of your example: first, use `$(shell)` without involving the cache; then, I will let NDK to run wildcard, but my logic will have a chance to prepare the post-truth.

Comment: That will work as long as you're sure nothing will try to cache the directory before you do it.  Feels a little rickety to me but...

Comment: Yes, this is a true concern. But in my case, the directory where NDK will be looking for the file, is something it has no chance to stumble by before I explicitly point it to.